# How do I convert NSString to NSData?

Tags: cocoa, unicode, nsstring, nsdata

I have this line of code to convert NSString to NSData:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:[message UTF8String] length:[message lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

How do I do this in Unicode instead of UTF8? My message may contain cyrillic characters or diacritical marks.

Comment: Define "Unicode". It's not an encoding (not strictly speaking at least). UTF-8 is perfectly capable of encoding all Unicode characters, so it should be sufficient for your use.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First off, you should use `dataUsingEncoding:` instead of going through `UTF8String`. You only use `UTF8String` when you need a C string in that encoding.

Then, for “Unicode” (specifically, UTF-16), just pass `NSUnicodeStringEncoding` instead of `NSUTF8StringEncoding` in your `dataUsingEncoding:` message.